# 7V or 12V Power Supplies for Arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, power, voltage, voltage-regulator

The recommended input voltage for Arduino is 7-12V. Given that both 7V and 12V power supplies (AC-to-DC converters) are available, which voltage will be more suitable/practical? Could be in terms of factors like energy efficiency, costs, heat generation etc...

Comment: The real answer? Use a usb charger on the usb port, for a stable 5v with no heat issues on the board, higher capacity (must usb chargers are 1+ Amp at this point), and pretty cheap (5 dollars retail, and you can buy them everywhere to boot)

Comment: @Passerby, would that kind of charger fall into the category this user describes? : [*"it must be a real stable 5V (not some wacky unregulated wall-wart)"*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/73455/221420)

Answer (score 6):

The Arduino uses a linear regulator to convert the input voltage to 5V to run the logic. Any excess voltage gets converted to heat in proportion to the current being drawn (P = ΔV × I), therefore, you want to use the *lowest* acceptable voltage.

The regulator is physically very tiny, and has little if any effective heat-sinking to help it manage power dissipation, so the current that it can handle is very limited — basically the needs of the Arduino itself plus a few 10s of mA to operate external circuitry. Reducing the input voltage as much as possible allows you to get a few more mA out of it before it shuts down.